# How do you remove extra empty space in NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

is there a simple way to remove the extra spaces in a string?  ie like...

```
NSString *str = @"this string has extra              empty spaces";
```

result should be:

```
NSString *str = @"this string has extra empty spaces";
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

replace all double space with a single space until there are no more double spaces in your string.

```
- (NSString *)stripDoubleSpaceFrom:(NSString *)str {
    while ([str rangeOfString:@"  "].location != NSNotFound) {
        str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@" "];
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, fluchtpunkt! i was hoping there was a one liner or something :)  cheer!

Comment: No other direct / documented way?