# NSString removing spaces and leaving only one

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you remove extra empty space in NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870298/how-do-you-remove-extra-empty-space-in-nsstring)

i'm trying to figure out how to remove all spaces from a string but leave only one.
That is if i have a string like

```
"this    is  my     test  string"
```

the result would be

```
"this is my test string"
```

Thanks

**Update**: Found the answer here
[Removing multiple spaces in NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136970/removing-multiple-spaces-in-nsstring)

Comment: @teo : That is good to find answer yourself, and even the best one using regex... :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one:

```
NSString *string=@"this    is  my     test  string";

NSCharacterSet *spaces = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"];
NSArray *tempArray = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:spaces] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
string = [tempArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```